# How to Empty TextBox Text in an event windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, textbox, keyup

I want to Empty The Text which is by default written in the textbox  , i can empty it by doing

```
Textbox1.Text="";
```

but i want to know, which event should i exactly use ?will it be  GotFocus,KeyEnter,Keyup,Tap or any other method .

Comment: Go mad, use a custom event.

Comment: Your choice. When do _you_ want to write the default text? Personally i do itwhen i create the textbox, but if you want to empty it every time th euser tries to type something in it, go for the KeyUp event. If you want to empty it every time it gets focus, go with GotFocus. It largely depends on how aggressive your users are and how far away they are..

Comment: Leave when to clear it to the user, provide a control to do so.

Comment: i also do it when i create the textbox ! then how to empty it ?

Comment: So, when exactly do you want your textBox to clear? Do you want to clear it when user starts typing into it? Then use GotFocus. Want to clear it when he hits a button? Then use the button's Click/Tap event... specify the scenario in which you want to clear the textbox...

Comment: do you want to implement Hint or placeholder in textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is using on GotFocus and LostFocus. On GotFocus the code should be something like this:

```
if (textbox1.Text == "My default text...")
            textbox1.Text = "";
```

Just to make sure to no delete a text previously entered by the user. And on LostFocus just something like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text))
            textbox1.Text = "My default text...";
```

So again you are checking to no delete a user entered text.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhoneTextBox of WPToolkit, which will maintain that functionality on its own